# Bash if - Exit code shows 0 when it shouldn't?

Tags: bash, if-statement, exit-code

I couldn't find this question anywhere - please let me know if it's a duplicate.

I'm trying to figure out why the **exit code ($?) is 0** in this Bash if statement, when 254.254.254.254 obviously doesn't exist:

```
if [[ `ping -c 1 254.254.254.254` ]];then
  echo "Yes - $?"
else
  echo "No - $?"
fi

Yes - 0
```

After experimenting with if [[ ` ` ]] a little bit, it looks like it's evaluating true if there is ever any output on `stdout`, whether the output was desired or not, whether an error was returned or not.  I'd thought that testing for exit code `$?` would alleviate that problem, but apparently not?

If you run `ping -c 1 254.254.254.254;echo $?` you'll get the proper exit code, `1`.  Why doesn't that show up in my if statement?

Comment: I suggest to use `if ping -c 1 254.254.254.254; then`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't checking the exit code of `ping`; you are checking if it wrote anything to standard output. You code is equivalent to

```
if [[ -n $(ping -c 1 254.254.254.254) ]]; then
```

and `$?` is the exit code of `[[ ... ]]` (which is why you ended up in the "Yes" branch in the first place).

To check the exit code, don't capture the output, and don't use it inside a `[[ ... ]]` command.

```
if ping -c 1 254.254.254.254; then
```

Comment: When I tested "ping -c 1 254.254.254.254" by itself without backticks / $(), I was putting it in the [ and [[ brackets, not straight-to-terminal, and kept getting errors about too many arguments.  That was my mistake.  Thank you for the explanation; should I delete this question?